# Building a JSON search parser

Tags: java, android, json, search, android-studio

I am working with a database api and they give me the opportunity to search using a url through their database.

This is the url =

```
http://api.database.com/v2/search?q=(THE PRODCUT)&type=(THE TYPE OF PRODUCT)
&key=(myApiKey)
```

I want to make a simple search bar were the user can type the product name and choose a type (catagorie) to insert that into the url and then look the product up in the database.

I know how I can parse the data from the url but how can I insert the users text into the url to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a better approach to use URI to build your search url.

Try something like this

```
final String FORECAST_BASE_URL ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .build();
URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
```

And then read the response from the inputStream.

```
 InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation or you can use String.format(String format, Object... args). For example:

```
String url = String.format("http://api.database.com/v2/search?q=%s&type=%s&key=%", product, productType, apiKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

or :

```
var product = "Product";
var productType="ProductType";
var url = "http://api.database.com/v2/search?q="+product+"&type="+productType+"&key="+myApiKey;
```